# SciChart Donut chart in Android

Tags: android, scichart

How to add text in the center of  donut chart in android? I tried seriesName but it didn't work.

```
val donutSeries: IPieRenderableSeries = sciChartBuilder.newDonutSeries().withSegments(
            *vehicleSegmentList(vehicleList).toTypedArray()
donutSeries.seriesName = "Hello"
```

The above didn't set "Hello" in the center of donut.
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such API for donut chart yet. If you want you can create a feature request on [SciChart website](https://www.scichart.com/feedback-policy/) to add it.

If you want you can easily workaround this limitation by placing TextView on top of the chart. Just place TextView and chart into common ViewGroup (e.g. into PercentFrameLayout or ConstraintLayout ) and using LayoutParams place it in the center of chart.